# Getting data from React Context

Tags: reactjs

In my Context, I am doing an API call on initialisation to get user data, setting this to a userData state hook, before passing it down to all my children components.

Context:

```
// Initialise
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{
  const getUserData = async () => {
    let response = await axios.post("*API ENDPOINT*", {
      jwt: getCookie("jwt")
    })
    setUserData(response.data)
  }
  
  getUserData()
  
},[])

return (
    <TrackerContext.Provider value={userData}>
      {children}
    </TrackerContext.Provider>
)
```

However, when I try and access the 'userData' property in my children's useEffect initialisation, it doesn't exist immediately, as it takes time for 'setUserData' to actually change the state of the userData hook.

Child Component:

```
const userData = useContext(UserContext)

useEffect(()=>{
  alert(userData)
}, [])
```

As a result, the above code alerts a 'NULL' because userData does not exist immediately. Is there a way to get userData immediately, and use this value in the useEffect of my child components?

Comment: No, because you are waiting on an asynchronous call, while render happens synchronously.

Comment: Short answer is no it is not possible to make an api call instantaneously, You also don't control exactly when react updates the components. Check out [axios hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks) it's a nice lib built on top of axios that has simple examples to handle loading and errors.

Comment: The usual approach is either to give useful default values while the real data is being fetched, or handle the `null` value in the render, by showing a loading spinner for example.

Comment: This is partially the purpose of concurrent mode in Beta. It will allow you to throw a promise (and therefore not render the component) if the data isn't ready yet. Then it will try again when the promise resolves (ie the data is retrieved). In this case you could check if data was there, if not throw a promise that is the data's promise (the provider would have to provide this promise... ie not use async await and give the promise).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your child component with adding change dependency in useEffect. Check below code sample:

```
const userData = useContext(UserContext)

useEffect(()=>{
    alert(userData)
}, [userData])
```